# Scala - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: scala

I have seen other threads about this but none of them answered my question. The fact is I think that in my case the problem is not like the others.

Here is a link to the problem I tried to solve: http://projecteuler.net/problem=55

I am sure the algorithm is correct but what I suspect is that there is something going on with what Scala can convert to string. I don't know. Here is my code:

```
package projecteuler55

object PE55 extends App {



 def rev ( x :BigInt) : BigInt = {
  x.toString.reverse.toInt 
 }



 def notPalindrome ( x:BigInt) : Boolean = { 
   if ( x != rev(x) ) true else false
 }

 def test (x:BigInt , steps:Int) : Boolean = {

    if ( steps > 50 ) true
    else if (notPalindrome(x) == false) false
    else test ( x + rev(x) , steps +1)
   } 

 var lychrel = 0
 for (i<-10 until 10000){
   if (test(i+rev(i),0)) lychrel += 1
 }
 println(lychrel)

}
```

and the error I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2284457131"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$.rev(PE55.scala:8)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$.notPalindrome(PE55.scala:14)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$.test(PE55.scala:20)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVI$sp(PE55.scala:26)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$delayedInit$body.apply(PE55.scala:25)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at projecteuler55.PE55$.main(PE55.scala:3)
    at projecteuler55.PE55.main(PE55.scala)
```

Why does this happen? I also use `BigInt` in case of an overflow but this does not seem to help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `x.toString.reverse.toInt` uses plain ints, not BigInt. hence the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toInt` expects a string that can be parsed to fit into a regular `Int`, which 2284457131 can't.  You want to use `BigInt(x.toString.reverse)`.

Comment: Oh I did not know you can use BigInt like this. This was what I was looking for. Thank you!